# How can I turn off animations in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

How can I turn off animations in Google Chrome?

Example of actions that trigger animations:

- Opening a new tab
- Closing a tab
- Downloading a document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `--wm-window-animations-disabled` parameter when launching Chrome:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --wm-window-animations-disabled
```

[image]

Comment: This has no effect whatsoever on the Chrome UI.  Hovering a tab until the preview appears, is animated.  Moving the mouse from tab to tab animates the preview sideways from tab to tab.  All three of the OP's points - opening/closing tabs and downloading files, remain animated.

Answer (score 4):

There are no options for disabling Chrome UI animations. There are also no provisions for adjusting Chrome's UI animations via code such as through extensions or themes.

[This ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8944) asking for that capability has been around (and ignored) for years.