# How to disable chrome "new window animation"?

Tags: google-chrome, default-settings

Chrome used to open new window just like that:
new window appears.

Now new windows appear with animation:
it starts with a smaller window (~80%), then it increases to full screen.

How to disable this animation?

Chrome Version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit) on Ubuntu

(other windows appear without animations)

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I turn off animations in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1140564/how-can-i-turn-off-animations-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the animation by adding the `--wm-window-animations-disabled` command-line flag.

For Linux/Ubuntu you can make this permanent by editing the Chrome shortcut at `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`. There are 3 `Exec=` lines where you will need to add `--wm-window-animations-disabled` immediately after the executable name.

If you find that this is no longer working, re-check your shortcuts as some Chrome updates (via a package manager) could have overwritten the shortcut(s), so you may need to re-edit them.

Comment: thank you so much! (because of this i already started switching to firefox... but now back to chrome)

Comment: This isn't working for me. Ubuntu 17.04 Chrome 58.0.3029.110 i3 desktop.

Also this question is repeated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607461/google-chrome-disable-window-animations

Comment: mscdex, why would you remove my addition to your answer ? giving a single command fix sounds like a good idea to me. Especially when you have to repeat after each updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the flag `--wm-window-animations-disabled` to all shortcuts used to launch Chrome with the following command:

```bash
sudo replace "Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable" "Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --wm-window-animations-disabled" -- /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```